# Shimano Hydraulic Disc Brakes vs Tektro Hydraulic Disc Brakes

Tags: brakes, shimano, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

My current bike has this brake set: "Tektro HD-M285 post mount hydraulic disc brakes with 160mm 6-bolt rotors and Tektro levers."
I have read many places online that people prefer "Shimano M315, hydraulic disc, 160mm." I am considering an upgrade, but I have yet to see any scientific fact behind which brand is more appropriate for certain environments. Is this truly a matter of opinion or is there factual evidence to prove that one is more efficient and durable than the other?

Comment: Are you happy with your current set up?  What exactly would you be looking for? less weight? better stopping power? more modulation?

Comment: I am not terribly concerned with weight. The brakes I have worked well, but I am wondering if either has been proven more durable. Like is one expected to last for a greater number of miles than another because I would prefer to invest in a long-term component rather than a short-term component?

Comment: Based on Amazon pricing, you are looking at the Shimano brakes being more than twice as expensive.  If longevity is your main concern, I would ride what you have until you have an issue then look to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, @BenKickert This makes sense. I saw the price difference, but I just wasn't sure if there is any more to it than just a name. I appreciate your help!

Comment: If you are going to upgrade, I would go at least to the M7000 to add the extra adjustability and also interoperability with the top of the line Shimano components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on what you are looking for.  Both the Tektro HD-M285 and the Shimano M315 are considered entry-level hydraulic brakes (despite the fact the M315s are over twice the cost), so if your current setup works for you, I wouldn't change it.

If you were looking to upgrade your brakes, I would go with the Deore (M6000) or SLX model (M7000).  At that point you are going to get quite a few additional features.  For instance, the M7000 has tool-free reach adjustment along with a few other weight savings and some minor increased performance upgrades (better pistons for instance).

The nice thing about getting into this upper range is you can easily swap individual components with the higher Shimano ranges.

Personally I would save up for the M7000s.